# pytorch: implementing a custom optimizer

Tags: python, pytorch, stochastic-gradient

I'm trying to implement a slightly different version of SGD with pytorch and test it on some datasets. I need to write a custom optimizer on which to train my model, however I cannot find any guide which explains how to do so. Is anyone able to tell me how I can proceed or suggest me any useful reference?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you have a look at the internal implementation of SDG in PyTorch?

Comment: @Ivan I did but to me it's not clear how they proceed. At a certain point an sgd function is called which I was not able to find in the documentation (the F.sgd... at the end, https://pytorch.org/docs/master/_modules/torch/optim/sgd.html)

Comment: You should look at the GitHub source code instead: here is [`torch.optim.SGD`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/optim/sgd.py#L144). Then you can jump onto the functional definition itself [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/aab67c6dff3819d3c05b328e964f1642227adbe6/torch/optim/_functional.py#L156).